# What is the most extensible way to manage Django UI choices that correspond to Python functions?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, extensibility

I am trying to create a static shared list of functions and their descriptions to display in a `Django` `form` `MultipleChoiceField`.

I want this to be extensible in case I add more file options later on, but I don't want to have to change the code in multiple places beyond writing the new function and adding it to a `CHOICES` list in my **tasks.py** file.

I can't seem to reference the functions (`a`, `b`, and `c`) from my `CHOICES` list outside the class. I have tried `TaskClass.a` in the list, but I keep getting the error:

```
Unresolved reference 'a'
```

What's the best way to do this?

**tasks.py**

```
CHOICES = [
    ('This is function A.', a),
    ('This is function B.', b),
    ('This is function C.', c)
]

class TaskClass():
    def a(self):
        ...

    def b(self):
        ...

    def c(self):
        ...
```

**form.py**

```
from tasks import CHOICES

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    function_choices = []

    # Convert function choices to list format needed for MultipleChoiceField
    for i, tuple in enumerate(CHOICES):
        function_choices.append((i+1, tuple[0]))

    forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=function_choices,
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            label='Functions to Call:'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a mapping layer between the string values and the function names:

```
CHOICES = [
    ('a', 'This is function A.'),
    ('b', 'This is function B.'),
    ('c', 'This is function C.'),
]

class TaskClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.task_map = {
            'a': self.a,
            'b': self.b,
            'c': self.c
        }

    def a(self):
        ...

    def b(self):
        ...

    def c(self):
        ...
```

Then you can run the appropriate function by calling:

```
tc = TaskClass()
tc.task_map['a']()
```